# Загрузка pdf файла через визуальный редактор tinymce

Tags: pdf, javascript, tinymce

Добрый день, форумчане! Возникла у меня потребность загрузить, кроме картинок, файл формата pdf. Кнопки в редакторе нет. Нашел в сети рекомендации, что в настройках редактора, в разделе `"theme_advanced_buttons"` добавить параметр `"file"`, но после этого кнопка на панели не появилось. Возможно нужен плагин или его активация? Может кто сталкивался и решил подобную проблему? Заранее благодарен за ответ по теме.

Answer (score 1):

в тини насколько я знаю загрузчик платный, или что то изменилось?
[[@Expert](/users/6/expert)](/users/6/expert) там просто надо создать ссылку, выделив слово, затем нажать на "звено", рядом с полем для ввода ссылки будет кнопочка, жмем туда и загружаем файлы любые.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался))) Загрузить файл любого формата можно, если начать создавать/редактировать ссылку через редактор...

Comment: @aavd, Поясните Ваш ответ. Возможно, в дальнейшем, он сможет помочь кому-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/

Штука очень неплохая. Только внимательно читай документацию, там есть пара подводных камней. Ну и лично мне пришлось этот плагин очень сильно допиливать под свои нужды (правда пока я разбирался в коде - я чуть не поседел).